# How do I know if a mouse pointer is over a particular element on the page?

Tags: javascript

With the help of JavaScript, of course.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event4.shtml

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to handle the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event for the elements:

```
element.onmouseover = function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    alert("You moused over "+element.outerHTML);
}
element.onmouseout = function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    alert("You moused out of "+element.outerHTML);
}
```

You can also use [`document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) if the element is the topmost element at those co-ordinates:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
document.documentElement.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
}
function getElementUnderMouse()
{
    return document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Obviously if you have certain elements that prevent propagation/bubbling of the `onmousemove` event the mouse position could be incorrect whilst hovering over those elements.

Answer (score 2):

The onMouseover, onMouseout events fire.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, if you mouse over a div, it will become blue.

If you place the onmouseover to the full BODY, then you can then check on a condition(ID, className, tagName,...) if you want to do something on the element you are overing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>so</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <script>
        document.body.onmouseover = function(ev){
            var elm = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
            if(elm.tagName === 'DIV'){
                elm.style.backgroundColor = "#DEF";
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```